# Why is my root partition running out of space so quickly?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-usage

My root partition is already out of space and I installed Ubuntu like 3hrs ago, I just have a few apps on it, if you needed to know, I have a 120GB SSD.

[image]

Comment: So far as I can see, `gparted` is just telling you that all of `sda3` has been allocated as a LVM2 physical volume (PV) - it doesn't tell you anything about how much space has been used *within* the volume. Is there an actual issue that you are trying to solve?

Comment: No, it says all my storage is already used in the root partition.
https://imgur.com/a/0SOlPG4

Comment: This is normal for a LVM disk volume to look like that... like it's full... but it's not.

Comment: So... Can I use it like normally? Also, what do I do when the file manager says the disk it's full when I'm extracting something?

Comment: Can you post output of `df -h`?  This command displays the usage of file systems, and you should be able to see if `/` is (near) full or not.  gparted just tells you the partition size, and how much of it lvm has taken.  But "taken by lvm" does not mean it is not free to use for you.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/n86GsSxb

Comment: So your root partition (/) has not run out of space.

Comment: Okay, but still. What can I do when the extracting tool says it's out of space?

Comment: Could you run the extraction tool with `LC_ALL=C` in front of the path of the tool to show English version of the dialog box about the error?

Comment: What is that tool? Is there an issue with other tools?

Comment: The default extraction tool that comes with Ubuntu, and, nope, there's no problem with any other tools.

Comment: Maybe you should file a bug report about the program, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs